# Best practice to call a plugin on every page in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I created a plugin which I want to call on any page in my application. How can I do this, without creating a `mounted` function on every page and call that plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combo of layouts + middleware.

Layouts official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#layouts

Middlewares official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/

---

An app wide-global middleware would be feasable in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ['global'],
  },
}
```

with the `global` file in `middleware/global.js`.

---

Depending on how you created your plugin, you could simply register it globally too

```js
// plugins/fancy-plugin.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { myFancyPlugin } from 'fancy-plugin'

Vue.use(myFancyPlugin)
```

And don't forget to add it to the configuration

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/fancy-plugin' },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I can't get any further with the registration of the plugin. I don't quite understand the concept and have already looked at the documentation. The middleware already works, but not on a complete page refresh. Then it is called undefined, whenever I call it. But if I switch pages after loading the application the plugin is registered. And it's my own written Plugin, with the inject method

Comment: I guess that it's more of a plugin issue than an install one. Did you followed some specific tutorial for the creation and are you sure that it works fine when imported manually ? Does it support some specific hooks ?

Comment: The plugin is not written by me but by a colleague. I myself am pretty new to vuejs and nuxt. The plugin is built as a class which has methods in them. At them bottom it injects it to the plugins. So I can call it by this.$ChatApi.switchPage(). But as I said on a "hard" reload it is undefined. Can I share you the whole plugin file?

Comment: If it works when navigating within your app but not after a hard refresh, it's pretty much the way that you instaciate the plugin. The best, fastest and more secure answer here, would be to ask the creator of the plugin. That way, you will use it as intended. Also, what did you tried so far ? It does not get registered on a global middleware ? Some code of your Nuxt lifecycle would be helpeful. Maybe start by trying to `console.log('test')` at the same place where you do call the plugin too, too see if this one is fine for the loading.

Comment: The middleware is globally attached and works on any page. But only not on the hard refresh. Else it works super fine. At the plugins config the ssr is set to false. But I am now in contact to the creator. Thank you for your help  :-)

Comment: `ssr: false` is the old variant, you should use mode: `client`, or `server` or nothing as stated here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#object-syntax Be sure that your Nuxt is up to date too, this may have some impact. Otherwise, glad that I helped somehow and good luck for further investigation! :)